# Convert coordinate system (data vs shapefile)

Tags: r, geospatial, geo, coordinate-systems

My data and shapefile (both for the same city) both have geospatial coordinates, but in different coordinate reference systems.

*The coordinates in the data are as follows:*

1. 51.40633 | 0.015208
2. 51.40165 | 0.014715
3. 51.40253 | 0.015171

*The coordinates of the shapefile are as follows:*

1. 544173.0 | 184701.4
2. 544180.2 | 184700.2
3. 544180.3 | 184700.6

I would like to convert the coordinate system in the data to match the coordinate system used in the shapefile. Thank you!

##################
update:

> pts <- cbind(epcp1$longitude,epcp1$latitude) #coordinates of homes
> based on postcode
>
> #transform coordinates to same as shapefile (area level coordinates)
>
> pts = SpatialPoints(pts, proj4string = CRS(proj4string(shapefile)))

Comment: How are you reading the data in to R, as `sf` objects?

Comment: Data are .csv file with long and lat. I then transform using the "SpatialPoints" function in the sp package

Comment: Can you add that extra detail to your question please so we can see the code you already have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you can use `spTransform` from `sp`. But you need to make the first SpatialPoints object with its native CRS:

```
pts <- cbind(epcp1$longitude,epcp1$latitude) 
# assuming WGS84...
pts = SpatialPoints(pts, proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))

pts_reproj <- spTransform(pts, CRSobj = CRS(proj4string(shapefile)))
```